# How to log the events about the client boot from any live disks in windows server?

Tags: boot, windows-event-log, eventviewer, window-server-2012

Are there any ways to find out whether any clients boot from a live disk for example `Active Boot Disk`?

How to log that into windows server events log?

Thanks in advanced.

Server: Windows Server 2012.
Clients' OS: Windows 7.

Comment: For clarification: if any client in your network boots from a Live CD you want to log this to a Windows Server 2012?

Comment: Yes. I'd like to log that.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.

Before the computer is booted, there is no software running that has the capability to send data to a log server. You would need a custom BIOS for that.

Your best bet is to lock down BIOS with supervisor passwords and booting from PXE, then program a custom PXE environment option that allows booting from drives, but sends SNMP messages or similar when the option is chosen. You should be able to code something like this with fog.

Comment: I have been set the supervisor password of BIOS, however, some users such as hardware administrator must have the supervisor password. So I'd like to log their boots from Live Disk. Could you help me how to manage that with PXE programing please?